# I don't understand how 'exists' works in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I understand when 'Exists' and 'Not Exist' return true or false, and I know if it returns false nothing will be retrieved, but if it returns true, what will be retrieved?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return the values that you specified in your query (provided you don't have other elements in your WHERE clause that return false and are connected with a logical AND with your existence check.)

In other words: 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS' works like any other condition in your WHERE clause. Each of them will either return true or false and that will evaluate according to the rules of Boolean algebra.

You can play around with these examples here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp